# Leaflet (JavaScript Library)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was looking at the documentation for Leaflet (JavaScript mapping Library) and am trying to get a general sense of how things are working.

For example, it says the map can be initialized like this:

`var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);`

Is it correct to say that L itself is an object (already created 'behind-the-scenes' using something like `var L = new SomeObject(...)`?) And L has a method `map(...)` that creates a Map Object, and then Map also has a method `setView(...)` that allows itself to modify its properties, etc.?

(Sorry I'm new to all this... thanks! :)

Comment: `L` is a [global anonymous object](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.1.0/dist/leaflet-src.js#L8); that is, it's not an instance of a particular class. It's created as an empty object - `{}` - and the methods, etc. are added to it. It is an object, but it serves as a namespace.